# mule timestamp in GMT in (java class and not in xml coding)

Tags: mule, mule-el

The below code works fine within a mule xml transformer

```
<xml:context-property key="myRecordCreateTimeStamp" value="#[server.dateTime.withTimeZone('GMT').format('MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm:ss')]"/>
```

If I want to achieve the same thing in a Java class inside a Mule ESB project,
which classes should I implement? And what is the equivalent class inside MuleEvent object?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using  Joda Time in java component to do this.

Use Imports

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Example

```
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm:ss" ).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(new Date());
    String gmtDateString = parser.print(dateTime);
```